# How to change Font size for PDF in iPad running iOS 9?

Tags: ipad, font, ios, books

I have iPad mini 2 running iOS 9. I'm transferring my PDFs to the iPad via iTunes.

I swear that I didn't find any option to increase font size in iBooks, not even in iBooks settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. I can't find any way to adjust font size on PDFs using iBooks for iOS, nor can I find anything about it online. Apparently, one can only adjust the font size with books in iBooks and not PDFs.